# LEGO Friends lost instructions

Tags: instructions, friends

Where do I find instructions for LEGO Friends that my daughter has managed to lose but are also discontinued?

Answer (score 4):

You can find downloadable copies of LEGO instructions for any set (there might be a few exceptions but not for standard retail sets) at the LEGO web site: https://wwwsecure.us.lego.com/en-us/service/buildinginstructions

Answer (score 0):

You can buy instructions at Brick Link web site: https://www.bricklink.com/browseList.asp?itemType=I&catString=771